# Exception in netty io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException:

Tags: java, netty

I am new to netty and learning the basis of nettty but when i add some part

sendResponseHtml(request, ctx.channel(), HttpResponseStatus.OK, array);

after i am getting following error. can any one suggest the reason behind the exception . and i am not able to handle where the exception occured.

```
io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: AbstractChannel$CloseFuture@3b8e2477(incomplete)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:391)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultChannelPromise.java:157)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.await(DefaultPromise.java:252)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.sync(DefaultPromise.java:219)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
    at com.gps.concurrent.ffdfdfd.exceptionCaught(ffdfdfd.java:4045)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:271)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:249)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:79)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:271)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:249)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:271)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:249)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:775)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:156)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You MUST NOT call ChannelFuture.sync() in your ChannelHandler.

Comment: @Norman - The sync from the handler was indeed my issue and clearing it fixed it so thank you.  Can you give some background as to what is happening in the code to make that statement a poor choice?

Comment: all listeners are fired from the eventloop thread (which also executes ChannelHandler methods). If you call .sync from the channelHandler method, you block the eventLoop, which is a deadlock